# Jquery filter() doesn't work with class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a newbie web developer. I am stuck in somewhere and I need your help. I have a filter() which works perfectly fine when I use it with an ID selector such as **('#test')**. But when I try to pick the same element with it's class like **('.locate')**, It doesn't work. By the way, **$(result)** comes from another html file via AJAX.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="test" class="locate">About Me</h1>
```

JS:

```
var outcome=$(result).filter('#test'); //It works
var outcome=$(result).filter('.locate'); //It doesn't
```

EDIT: Just now, I realized if it is a string that I give in html() or text(), it works. But if it is the variable itself,it doesn't. Here, jsfiddle.net/3UeSK/2

Comment: you forgot the quotation mark? `filter('.locate');` or just mistake in posting question?

Comment: Superio, next time you post a question here, stay around in case you get a fast comment that you can answer directly.

Comment: What, no Pedro, the question itself contains `('.locate')`, meaning Superio is competent enough to spot a missing quote.

Comment: @Brian: no, it means he was paying attention when he typed that into the question, *not* that his attention didn't slip when he was typing his original code, *or* when he was copying from his code to the question itself.

Comment: I am really sorry that I wasn't around, I wasn't expecting such a fast comment. The typo is in the question only, original code doesn't have it. @PedroEstrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @PedroEstrada is right.  You can see the working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3UeSK/1/

```
<h1 id="test" class="locate">About Me</h1>
<h2 id="result"></h2>

var result = $("h1");
var outcome = $(result).filter('.locate');
if(outcome.length > 0){
    $("#result").text("found it");
} else {
    $("#result").text("didn't find it");
}
```

Comment: Just now, I realized if it is a string that I give in html() or text(), it works. But if it is the variable itself,it doesn't. Here, http://jsfiddle.net/3UeSK/2/

Comment: Right.  The variable is an object.  You could do something like this though: `$("#result").html(outcome.text());`